# Timeout inserting 1,000,000 of rows in database (sometimes)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.0, Entity Framework 6.1.3 and SQL Server 2012.

I have this stored procedure that I call with `Ado.net`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCodes]
      @codes as dbo.SerialAndValueList READONLY -- Codes
    , @username nvarchar(50)            
    , @source nvarchar(50)              
    , @column2 tinyint                  
AS
    Declare @codesCount int;

    set nocount on;

-- =========== CODE =============   
    INSERT INTO Code (Serial, Column1, Column2, Column3, UserName, Source)
        SELECT Serial, Column1, @column2, @column3, @username, @source FROM @codes

    IF (@@ERROR != 0)
        RETURN -1 -- Database error

RETURN 0
```

And `SerialAndValueList`:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SerialAndValueList]
AS TABLE
(
    Serial nvarchar(20),
    Column1 tinyint
)
```

I'm using it to store 1,000,000 of Serials (`@codes` has 1,000,000 of rows).

I'm testing it with the same amount of codes and sometimes I get a time out exception, and other times not.

I have found the article [Configure the remote query timeout Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option) suggesting:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

But if I do this, I want to disable it only in this stored procedure (at the beginning), and re-enable it before leave it.

Another question is that the timeout occurs only 60 seconds after I run the stored procedure but reading here, [remote query timeout Option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/ms177457(v=sql.105).aspx), I see the default value is 600 seconds.

How can I get the current value of remote query timeout Option on my database?

Or, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try inserting in smaller chunks - say, 10 inserts of 100,000 rows each.

Comment: @ZoharPeled What is best? Split data or increment CommandTimeout? Maybe, many calls will trigger more than one call with more timeout.

Comment: I don't know what's best, It depends on too many variables. I just know that sometimes using more statements on fewer roes gets the job done faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Remote XXX timeout* values relate to timeouts for *outgoing* remote queries run on the server - e.g. an outgoing query to a linked server, the settings have no effect on *incoming* queries that come from a client.

If you want a higher timeout set `.CommandTimeout` which is available on `ObjectContext` & `SqlCommand`.